# YQL response null when it *shouldn't* be

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, yql

Use http://jobs.sitesixteen.com/ for reference.

I'm using YQL for the city, state auto-complete. IF you type "san", the [response from YQL](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?callback=jsonp1294734397302&q=select+name%2Cadmin1.code+from+geo.places+where+text%3D%22san%2a%22+and+country.code%3D%22US%22+limit+10+|+sort%28field%3D%22popRank%22%2C+descending%3D%22true%22%29&format=json&callback=cbfunc) is `null`. The odd thing I find is that if you type "los", the [response from YQL](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?callback=jsonp1294734397302&q=select+name%2Cadmin1.code+from+geo.places+where+text%3D%22los%2a%22+and+country.code%3D%22US%22+limit+10+|+sort%28field%3D%22popRank%22%2C+descending%3D%22true%22%29&format=json&callback=cbfunc) returns results as expected.

Is this a badly formed query and I'm just not seeing it, or something on Yahoo's end?

As always, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Don't think the issue is with YQL.To me it looks like something on the end of the places API (or whatever this URL is: http://where.yahooapis.com/v1/places.q). Are they specifying which data is searched when you specify the 'text' key? Looks like the data is indexed differently on their end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a response I received from Eddie Babcock of Yahoo!

> This request contains a remote filter (text="san*") and a local filter (country.code="US"). The remote filter invokes a web service that tries to find all town place names in the world that begin with "san", but because there are so many, a timeout occurs, and no results are returned. You will need to be more selective in your text value (add more starting characters) to allow the web service to complete the request. "los*" succeeds because there are fewer towns in the world that start with "los".

Which still leads me to believe it's an issue with the way they've implemented it, but at least this question is now resolved.

Comment: https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from html where url="http://www amazon in/Seiko-Premier-Analog-Blue-Watch/dp/B012T413GO?_encoding=UTF8&ref_=cm_sw_r_wa_apa_i_5c5uzbQG5A293" and xpath="//title|//head/meta|//head/link"&format=json&callback=?

This is  my url. WHere I'm going wrong? Any help?

Answer (score -1):

You aren't providing enough information.

Notice that by manually populating the State field on [that particular website](http://jobs.sitesixteen.com/) with `san` it never returns a list.

By modifying your query to `san f` (SAN space F) it will return the expected results.

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?callback=jsonp1294734397302&q=select+name,admin1.code+from+geo.places+where+text%3D%22san%20f*%22+and+country.code%3D%22US%22+limit+10+|+sort(field%3D%22popRank%22,+descending%3D%22true%22)&format=json&callback=cbfunc
```

**EDIT**

The site is designed this way.  This is a comment from the jQuery function that pulls the data back for the drop down list. It explains the logic behind the query.

`// select name,admin1.code from geo.places where text="medf*" and country.code="US" limit 10 | sort(field="popRank", descending="true")`

Notice how it's limited to 10?

Entering a search term that returns more than 10 results won't return any results.  Entering `san` produces more than 10 results so won't return anything where as entering `los` returns 3 results.

It isn't to do with inconsistencies in YQL.

Comment: It's not that I'm not providing enough information, it's that YQL provides inconsistent results when searching for "san" compared to "los". I am aware that "san f" provides results, but one would presume that it would take "los a" or "los g" to return results as well, when that is not the case. I am mostly just confused at Yahoo's inconsistency.

Comment: I built it, I know how it works. I don't think you quite understand YQL or basic QL syntax. The "limit 10" tells YQL I want a max of 10 results returned. I do this to speed up response time. This YQL console link ( http://y.ahoo.it/KCG6R1yI ) should illustrate how YQL actually works. Here you'll see the "los*" query limited to 2 results. Please do not response to questions you don't understand, it makes it much less likely someone knowledgeable will click on the question